# How can you get different objects working at different framerates working in html5 canvas?

Tags: html, animation, canvas

Say I want a ball bouncing at 5 frames per second and only want to have a square bouncing at 2 frames per second, how is this possible?

return setInterval(draw,10) is used in the current simulation to move 1000 particles around, but I also want to draw a radial gradient on a second canvas which gets data from the particle simulation. I cant figure out how to draw the gradient a frame per second and the particles at another framerate

Comment: perhaps I should have gone into more detail. At the moment I am using return setInterval(draw,10) which is at 10 frames a second (if possible) I cant seem to work out how to do it, 5 and 2 are just random numbers, it could be anything

Comment: These need to be returned in the main method, so I was confused as to if it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i do is create a Timer constructor, and everytime I make something animate, i make a var animateThing = new Timer().

It may not be necessary to do this, but it can be a useful peice of code as you get deeper into canvas with more moving parts.

**Update**
So something sorta like this.

```
function Timer(fps, callback) {
  return setTimout(callback, 1000 / fps);
}

var timer1 = new Timer(33, callback1);
var timer2 = new Timer(55, callback2);
```

Now that's probably not gonna work, but it's the idea.

Comment: so you mean.. making it go every 10 secs or so using the timer??

Comment: no make a timer object, and when you need to animate something, create a new timer and pass it the framerate. i updated with some code ^